# Short distances from reference point

Tags: 2d, algorithm

I would like to compute short distance from reference point in 2d grid. To expose:

- 0, 0: not penetrable
- 0, 1: not penetrable
- ...
- 1, 1: penetrable
- ...

[image]

I search an algorithm who return:

- 1, 1: 1
- 2, 1: 1
- 3, 1: 1
- 1, 2: 1
- 2, 2: 0
- 3, 2: 1
- ...
- 1, 6: 4
- 3, 6: 4

for `2, 2` reference point, `4` as maximum distance in exemple grid. What algorithm can to this (with good perf) ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: nah, it's just [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)... Dijkstra is used when some nodes can be passed through but have some specific cost; like passing through themare considered them, is considered two turn.

Comment: I agree with Ali.S — BFS will work well here. It's simple and fast. It also works if you have multiple reference points (see [demo](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/distance-to-any/)), which is handy for figuring out which reference point is closest to where you are.

Answer (score 1):

An possible algorithm, expsed in python language:

```
def get_distances_for_points(object_position, max_distance):
    points_distances = {}
    points_to_looks = [object_position]

    for current_distance in range(max_distance):
        new_points_to_looks = []
        for looked_point in points_to_looks:
            around_points = <here return around points of looked_point>
            for around_point in around_points:
                if around_point not in points_distances and <here return True if around point is penetrable and False if blocked (wall)>:
                    points_distances[around_point] = current_distance+1
                    new_points_to_looks.append(around_point)
        points_to_looks = new_points_to_looks

    return points_distances
```

And according to comment of  Ali.S and  amitp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search ([demo](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/distance-to-any/))